# How to find intersection of 2 longs in C?

Tags: c, intersection

How Would I compare 2 digits in C and find the intersection of each long in my program? I have the following code but I'm not sure why it is seg faulting. What I'm trying to do is compare 2 numbers and see if each digit  matches with each other. If they do then they will set the digit to the same number but if they are different it will set that digit to 0.
For example if I had number1=2421 and number2=2412 then the number returned would be 2400.

```
   long set_intersect( long number1, long number2 )
   {
        int count=0;
        char setone[18],settwo[18];
        int final[18];
        long countone,counttwo;
        while((number1) && ( number2))
        {
                countone = number1 %10;
                setone[count] = countone;
                counttwo = number2% 10;
                settwo[count] = counttwo;
                number1 = number1/10;
                number2 = number2/10;
                count++;
        }
        for( int i= 0 ; i< count; i++)
        {
                        if( setone[i] == settwo[i])
                        {
                                final[i] = setone[i];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                final[i] = 0;
                        }
        }
        for( i=0 ; i < count ; i++)
        {
                printf("%i\n",final[i]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Undefined behaviour due to uninitialised value for `count`.

```
int count = 0;
```

Comment: so after editing the code the code isnt printing out the correct intersection. Is there anything else in the code that would be causing this?

Comment: Probably.  Depends what you mean by "correct".  I imagine that if you gave 123356 and 12345 it would print out 123050.  Is that "correct"?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Hmm...  Oh, well in that case your while loop terminates too early.  It will stop as soon as either number reaches 0, so you'd get 12305 for that previous example.

Comment: So I tried using an OR operator and still not sure how to get the output correctly. Do you think you could give me a couple more pointers ?

Comment: I think you have been treating your program as a black box full of mystery, rather than something that can be explored and interrogated. You haven't explained to me at all what output you're actually getting, which suggests that you are thinking about it backwards. An incorrect value tells you much more about something than a correct value does. Use the incorrect result and figure out how your program arrived at that value. Step through your code with a debugger and examine values, or print out values inside loops. I think a bit of debugging time here is more useful to you than anything else.

Comment: I have been debugging for the last hour and I cant seem to reach a conclusion. When I put in the value 244800 as the first number i am getting the output 827732 for some reason. I have no idea why this isnt working. When ever I am simply getting the remainder adding to the list, and diving by 10 I am getting the value 8277732

Comment: And you've tried putting this at the top of your first loop? `printf( "number1=%ld number2=%ld\n", number1, number2 );`